Find all consensus locations of 2D line segment intersections
I have a set of line segments, subsets of which all intersect at some locations. The line segments are noisy though so the intersections points aren't exact and there are some erroneous line segments in the set too. What's a good robust algorithm for finding the most likely set of intersection points? My first though is using RANSAC to incrementally extract the most supported intersection points.


Sounds like you need to compute the full graph of intersections and do some clustering

This look a lot, in dual (parameter) space, like the detection of lines by Hough transform: each pixel in image space is a line in parameter space, and each line in image space is a point in parameter space. When a bunch of points are aligned and belong to the same line in image space, in parameter space you have a bunch of lines intersecting in a single point. This is how Hough detect lines. But not exactly, since points in image space are never exactly aligned.

Just mentioning to say that I would look at how Hough transform algorithm do, since, in parameter space, they have to solve that exact problem.

At school, we learn Hough transform with a simple histogram. So a 2D array, and along each line, you increase the cell. Peaks in that array are where you put your intersecting point. And to handle inexactitude, you use large enough cells, and then perform a finer average inside the winning cell.

But maybe there are other algorithm in practice. For example a hierarchical histogram (that is a quad-tree, for example). But again, I would look at how Hough is implemented. For example, since you mentioned RANSAC, you could use a "reverse Hough" strategy, and consider each line as a point in dual space, and try to find the  line in that dual space that fits the best all the points.

Note: the duality between points and lines are visible if you write the equation in homogeneous coordinates: a.x+b.y+c.z=0 => (x,y,z) is a point that belong to a line (a,b,c). But in dual space, you could as well say that it is (a,b,c) that is point that belongs to a line (x,y,z) whose equation is x.a+y.b+z.c=0. Without homogeneous coordinates, you can do the same using a.x+b.y=1, except for lines that pass through point (0,0)
